# Text field to Picklist

Tags: workflow, picklist, field-update

Is it possible to push the value of a text field into a picklist without using a trigger in salesforce?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Process Builder can do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use Process Builder.

1. Create a process for your object and select `Start the process`- "when a record is created or edited"

[image: Start the process when a record is created or edited]

2. Set criteria to check if your text field `Is Changed = true` or `Was Set = true`.

[image: Is Changed or Was Set]

3. Set action type as `Update Records`, click on your root object (shot 1) and hit save (shot 2).

[image: Select Object]
[image: Object is properly selected]

4. Set the `Field` as your picklist value, and make sure your `Value` is set to reference.

[image: Select field and value]

I used Account with some standard fields for simplicity, but you obviously will want to replace the object and fields.

Answer (score 1):

@Adrian is right on with Process Builder.

You could also do this with the Data Loader if it's more of a one-time thing.

It's certainly not best-practice to store text values in picklist fields. There are several places in the UI where your choices are presented as lookups (list views for example). You'll never be able to create views to filter on those values. But I'll assume you have a good reason to want to do this :)